# Jquery access variable from different scope

Tags: jquery

I have a calendar plugin that is initialized in calendar.js

```
! function($) {
    "use strict";

    var CalendarApp = function() {
        this.$calendar = $('#calendar'),
        this.$calendarObj = null
    };

    CalendarApp.prototype.init = function() {
        // Initialized calendar with a library function
        // this.$calendarObj = this.$calendar.calendar();
    }
}(window.jQuery),

$(window).on('load', function() {

    $.CalendarApp.init()
});
```

On another page where in document.ready function() I want to call method of calendar but it is undefined.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    // changeDate() is a function defined in calendar plugin
    // CalendarApp.$calendarObj.changeDate();
    // Getting changeDate is not function
});
```

Comment: it's unclear why you think $calendar would have a function called changeDate... where did you declare that? All you've done with $calendar during the setup is assign it a jQuery object targeting an element

Comment: changeDate function is inside calendar library which is accessible from function($) scope but not accessible from $("document").ready()

Comment: You will have to put the variable in the same scope. You can give the variable as a parameter to your scope like you do with jQuery if you want to use different names.

Comment: "changeDate function is inside calendar library" ... is it? We can't see it

Comment: Yes changeDate is inside library